# Bash: While loop-Error " No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, error-handling, while-loop, sh

I have some code that doesn't work. It's says, "No such file or directory", and crashes on line 27:

```
while [ $i  < $amount]
```

But I don't know why. Anyone?

```
#!/bin/bash
#WWGEN Aleandro

small=$(echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
big=$(echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
C=$(echo "\"")
D=$(echo '!')
E=$(echo ",.@#$%^&*()][{};:?-_+=")
F=$(echo "0123456789")

characters=$(echo $small$big$C$D$E$F)

while getopts ":cl:p:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    c) characters=$(echo $big$C$D$E$F);;
    l) length=$OPTARG ;;
    p) amount=$OPTARG ;;
  esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

i=0

echo "amount: $amount"
echo "length: $length"

while [ $i  < $amount]

do

echo  "test"
echo $characters | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g ' | sed 's/^$//g'| shuf -n $length | paste -sd ''

i=$[$i+1]

done
```

Output:

```
bash wwgen.sh -l 6 -p 5
amount: 5
length: 6
wwgen.sh: line 27: [: 0: binary operator expected
```

Wanted Output:
5 random generated passwords with length of 6 like this.

```
bash wwgen.sh -l 6 -p 5
amount: 5
length: 6
69:AY
O7H;=
64]Z
]^NL!
(&NW5
```

Comment: Because that runs the `[` command with arguments `$i` and `]`, redirecting stdin from `$aantal`.

Comment: Post text as text, not pictures of text.

Comment: Update, + English code

Comment: Run your script through http://shellcheck.net/. It will point out many of your errors.

Comment: Oke solved my problem whit your site :D. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you using command substitution for simple assignments? `small="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`

Answer (score 1):

```
while [ $i < $aantal ]
```

tries to do some stuff involving taking input from file $aantal which explains the message.

For inferior test use:

```
while [ $i -lt $aantal ]
```

Simple example to prove my point:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
a=2
while [ $i -lt $a ]
do
  i=$[i+1]
  echo $i
done
```

output:

```
1
2
```

However, if I don't define `a` I get:

```
./test.sh: ligne 3 : [: 0 : opérateur unaire attendu
```

(I'll let you perform the translation from french :))

Comment: while [ $i -lt $aantal ], doesn't work. I get error " wwgen.sh: line 27: [: 0: binary operator expected" . $aantal is a number like 6 or 7,....

Comment: probably because this time you did not define `$aantal` by not passing the proper option to your script (in a simple test I made this work). Please humor us and post as text as  melpomene asked. your screenshot hurt my eyes and I cannot even copy/paste to test fully.

Comment: Oke I updated the post!

Comment: not quite: please post full output with the suggested change too please.

Comment: Solved with your site :D

Comment: your first post (before the translation) did not have the error where you forgot the space after the `$aaxxxx` variable.